# jQuery Horror "effects", similar creepy effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well this is a longshot, but you can imagine that attempting to google "horror jquery" or "scary jquery" is not relevant to what I need:

Creepy jQuery effects or plugins. Something that would, for example, add animated static over an image or every 10 seconds produce a moan. Now yes I could do that all with jQuery already, but I'm wondering if any of you have maybe seen a halloween plugin or something especially creepy jQuery could do.

Comment: Too localized. Plugins are for reusable code. You might try searching for a plugin to play a sound. You're not going to find plugins to play specific sounds, that's not what a plugin is. As an aside, websites that produce sounds are evil.

Comment: This is an interesting question but might be too specific to get useful answers.

Comment: @meagar - what about video sites?

Comment: @Daniel Obviously if your site's express purpose is to play video or audio you get a pass. Way to be intentionally obtuse.